# jQuery DataTables not working with Horizontal Scroll

Tags: jquery, datatables

Code sample

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
      "sScrollY": "200px",
      "sScrollX": "100%",
      "bScrollCollapse": true
   });
});
```

It showing like blow image 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UwTNM.png

Comment: Have you read the documentation? https://datatables.net/reference/option/scrollX

Answer (score 0):

the scroll property is in pixels and true or false as:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('#dataTables-example').DataTable({
      "sScrollY": true,
      "sScrollX": true,
      "bScrollCollapse": true
   });
});
```

for more information read documentation datatables.net/reference/option/scrollX.